# How do I determine the currently available JVM heap size?

Tags: java, caching, jvm, heap-memory

I can use `freeMemory()` to get unallocated heap size, but the actual available memory is usually larger if my program needs more space because of the uncollected garbage. I wonder if there's a way to tell how much memory is currently available in Java.

Comment: This is not a common scenario.  There are no alternatives to `gc()`; there's no way to determine how much memory could be freed without freeing it.

Comment: You can not force a GC. You may execute `System.gc()` but it may ignore you.

Comment: jvm manage memory automatically , if you real  want control of the whole object lifecycle  ,why not c++ . and if you real invoke ```GC()```, it is not clean  jvm heap immediately with blocking , it would clean in some point in the future which is Imperceptible

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Instead post a question about your original problem of caching large objects with the details.